# How do you use .js id= multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in functions.js

```
$("a#example2").fancybox({
'overlayShow' : false,
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
transitionOut' : 'elastic'
```

and it works but brings up my only errors while validating as HTML5. This is because I am using six

```
id="example2"
```

instances in my gallery and it flags for multiple use. When I dug up the templates for this, it had example1, example2 etc. and I just converted all to the one I like. This is for a gallery on my website at http://www.shaneofalltrades.com. Thanks!

Comment: Multiple divs with the same id will no doubt bring up errors while validating. HTML calls for id to be unique for each element if assigned to it. Why not use a class like such: `$(a .example2").fancybox();`?

Comment: There is at least a single quote missing in the example code. Please *copy and paste* the original error-free code, hopefully as a *minimal test-case* or a link to such on jsfiddle or similar. The correct solution is to *never* allow the DOM to contain elements with duplicate IDs (because it's nice to avoid undefined behavior) and to adjust the selectors around this fact ;-)

Comment: I figured the problem out. The code works and is right, but using it as id= multiple times was the issue. I should know "identifier must be unique", but with changes to html syntax and my being new the program world I wanted to make sure I was not missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you don't. That's what classes are for.

```
<a class="fancy">....

$('.fancy').fancybox(.....
```

Comment: So this worked without creating a .css and no header information in html as blast_hardcheeze posted (about using css). Is either way acceptable?

Comment: The CSS would only style the classes. CSS is not required to create and reference classes in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

id= is intended to be an identifier unique to the whole DOM. class= allows you to group elements by a common identifier.

HTML:

```
<div class="someClass">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.someClass
{
  background:transparent;
  color:#990000;
}

.someClass div { ... }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.someClass').html()
$('.someClass div').html()
```

Comment: Thanks this looks as if it will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should be using `class="example2"` instead.

So your selector will look like: `$("a.example2").fancybox({...})`